# Performance main section callstack shows a function calling itself, but function is not recursive

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I wrote a meaningless JavaScript program to study how DevTools Performance tab works. My program does not have any recursion, however the Main section shows that function `test2` calls itself, see screenshot:

[image]

What does that mean? Is my function internally split into two? Or does it mean the report has inaccuracies by design?

Here is the program:

```
<p><a id="test1" href="#">Do stuff</a></p>
<script>
  function test1(e) {
    console.time('test1');
    var foo = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
      test2(foo, i);
    }
    console.timeEnd('test1');
  }

  function test2(foo, i) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 100000; j++) {
      if (i * j % 211 === 0) {
        test3(foo);
      }
      else {
        foo.push(i * i - i);
      }
    }
  }

  var k = 0;
  function test3(foo) {
    if (k++ % 1733 === 0) {
      console.count('test3');
    }
    foo = [];
  }

  document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener('click', test1);
</script>
```

Comment: That's weird. I can normally replicate it, but everything works as expected if I enable the "v8 runtime calll stats on timeline" experiment in DevTools settings (press shift 5 times to show it in the experiments tab).

Chrome also has a feature (or used to have) to show timings for some internal methods, so maybe that's confusing it.